# Using jQuery InsertBefore with variables

Tags: jquery

Lets say we have a

```
<ul>
    <li>Item 1</li>
    <li>Item 2</li>
    <li class="putbeforehere">Something Else</li>
</ul>
```

The following works fine:

```
var test = "<li>Test</li>";
var test = $(test);

test.insertBefore('.putbeforehere');
```

That works fine. However I need to use a variable within the () of insertBefore.

Example:

```
var here = $(something).find('.someclass').children('ul.list li.item');
```

So I have some data that's returned via AJAX, will call it "data".

```
var data = $(data);
data.insertBefore(here);
```

This does not work. What am I doing wrong?

Thank you!

Comment: What are you returning via ajax? What is `data` equal to, to begin with?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [jQuery's API](http://api.jquery.com/insertbefore/), you're allowed to put a jQuery element in place of the selector. So it should work.

Proof: http://jsbin.com/AsAYoye/1/edit

To debug your case, make sure that your `here` variable is defined *when it is executed*, and that `data` is a string of the HTML you want to insert.

Comment: Thank you for this. To be honest with you I monkeyed around for a while as I awaited help. I'm not sure what went wrong... I don't think it was a typo, but I started it from scratch based on your example and it works now. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

`here` is an empty set, `children` method only selects the *children* nodes, use `find` method:

```
var here = $(something).find('.someclass').find('ul.list li.item');
```

Or:

```
var here = $(something).find('.someclass')
                       .children('ul.list')
                       .children('li.item');
```